# ¿Cómo guardar la información de un select sin que pierdan los datos cuándo se actualiza la página?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

tengo una tabla de productos en él cuál recibo por método GET la "ID" del producto para después mostrar su información e ir modificándolo.

*Código de cómo recojo la ID del producto*

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
    //si existe buscamos si ya estaba agregado ese producto
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
      $arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
      $encontro = false;
      $numero = 0;
      for ($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
        if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_GET['id']){
          $encontro = true;
          $numero=$i;
        }
      }
      if ($encontro == true){
        $arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']=$arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']+1;
        $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
      }else{
            //No estaba el registro
        $tipo = "";
        $nombre = "";
        $descripcion = "";
        $res = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='.$_GET['id'])or die($conexion->error);
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
        $tipo = $fila[1];
        $nombre = $fila[2];
        $descripcion = $fila[3];
        $arregloNuevo = array(
          'Id' => $_GET['id'],
          'Tipo' => $tipo,
          'Nombre' => $nombre,
          'Descripcion' => $descripcion,
          'Bodega' => 'Sin asignar',
          'Cantidad' => 1,
          'ValorUnitario' => 0,
          'Descuento' => 0,
          'Impuesto' => 0,
          'ValorCargos' => 0,
          'ImpuestosRetencion' => 0,
          'Total' => 0
        );
        array_push($arreglo, $arregloNuevo);
        $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
      }
    }
  }else{
    //creamos la variable de sesion
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
      $tipo = "";
      $nombre = "";
      $descripcion = "";
      $res = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='.$_GET['id'])or die($conexion->error);
      $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
      $tipo = $fila[1];
      $nombre = $fila[2];
      $descripcion = $fila[3];
      $arreglo[] = array(
        'Id' => $_GET['id'],
        'Tipo' => $tipo,
        'Nombre' => $nombre,
        'Descripcion' => $descripcion,
        'Bodega' => 'Sin asignar',
        'Cantidad' => 1,
        'ValorUnitario' => 0,
        'Descuento' => 0,
        'Impuesto' => 0,
        'ValorCargos' => 0,
        'ImpuestosRetencion' => 0,
        'Total' => 0
      );
      $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
    }
  }
```

**Anexo código de la tabla en la cuál muestro los productos**

```
<table class="table table-sm" id="tablaContenido">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Tipo</th>
                        <th>Ítem</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Bodegas</th>
                        <th>Cant.</th>
                        <th>Vr. Unitario</th>
                        <th>Descuento</th>
                        <th>Imp Cargo</th>
                        <th>Vr.+Cargos</th>
                        <th>Imp Retención</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php
                      $total= 0;
                      $cont = 1;
                      if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
                        $arregloCarrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                        for ($i=0;$i<count($arregloCarrito);$i++){
                          $total = $total + ($arregloCarrito[$i]['ValorUnitario'] * $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']);
                          ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $cont; ?></td>
                            <td>
                              <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                <option>Producto</option>
                                <option>Activo Fijo</option>
                                <option>Gasto / Cuenta Contable</option>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><p><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Nombre']; ?></p></td>
                            <td><p><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Descripcion']; ?></p></td>
                            <td>
                              <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="bodegas">
                                <?php 
                                $query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM bodegas")or die("Error en la consulta"); 
                                if ($arregloCarrito[$i]['Bodega'] == 'Sin asignar') {
                                  echo '<option selected>Sin asignar</option>';
                                  while ($campo = $query->fetch_array()) {
                                    echo '<option>'.$campo['nombre'].'</option>';
                                  } }else{
                                    echo '<option>Sin asignar</option>';
                                    echo '<option selected data-id='.$arregloCarrito[$i]["Id"].'>'.$arregloCarrito[$i]['Bodega'].'</option>';
                                  } ?>
                                </select>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control text-center txtCantidad"
                                  data-precio="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['ValorUnitario']; ?>"
                                  data-id="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>"
                                  value="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                                </div>
                              </td>
                              <td><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['ValorUnitario']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Descuento']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Impuesto']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['ValorCargos']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['ImpuestosRetencion']; ?></td>
                              <td class="cant<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>">
                                $<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['ValorUnitario'] * $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>
                              </td>
                              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEliminar" data-id="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>">X</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $cont++;
                          } 
                        } ?>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Tengo un problema con la parte de las bodegas ya que yo necesito que se guarde la información por productos de cada bodega que selecciona la persona que guarda la información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cada vez que selecciono la bodega para el producto con ID = 1, automáticamente también se selecciona para la bodega con ID = 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una parte del código con las cantidades, que SÍ funciona independientemente, si cambio la cantidad del producto con ID=1 lo hace y se queda guardado sólo para ese ID=1

```
<td>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center txtCantidad"
                                      data-precio="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['ValorUnitario']; ?>"
                                      data-id="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>"
                                      value="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(".txtCantidad").keyup(function(){
       var cantidad = $(this).val();
       var precio = $(this).data('precio');
       var id = $(this).data('id');
       incrementar(cantidad,precio,id);
     });
      function incrementar(cantidad,precio,id){
       var mult = parseFloat(cantidad)* parseFloat(precio);
       $(".cant"+id).text("$"+mult);
       $.ajax({
         method:'POST',
         url:'./php/actualizar_carrito.php',
         data:{
           id:id,
           cantidad:cantidad
         }
       }).done(function(respuesta){
        $('#contenidoTotal').load('./ventas/total_compra.php');
      });
     }
```

**actualizar_carrito**

```
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
if ($_SESSION['id_user'] == "") {
  echo "<script>alert('Por favor inicie sesión primero!');
  window.location.href='../'</script>";
}
$arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++){
    //$arreglo[$i]['Bodega'] = $_POST['bodega'];
    if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_POST['id']){
        $arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']=$_POST['cantidad'];
        $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;
        break;
    }
    //$_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que así cómo la cantidad de cada producto queda guardado para el mismo, lo haga con el de las bodegas, si selecciono la bodega principal para la ID = 1 quede guardado para esa ID = 1 y no intervenga con el otro producto con ID = 2 y que trabajen por separado así sucesivamente dependiendo de los productos que incluya el cliente... ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: El carrito solamente se puede obtener de la session?
por lo que veo traes el carrito de la tabla productos?

Comment: Sí tengo una session['carrito] la cuál almacena toda la información de los productos y a través de este creo un array para insertar los productos y trabajar con ellos

Comment: estás aplicando ajax para el select?

Comment: Saludos. Espero orientarte bien; prueba quitando a `<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="bodegas">` el `id` (desde luego si no lo usas para nada o no usarlo no afecta tu lógica de negocio). Todos tus `select` tiene el mismo `id`; recuerda que en la página el `id` no debe repetirse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tip: el id de bodegas dentro del foreach se está repitiendo `id="bodegas"`

Recomiendo quitar el id en cada elemento de la tabla o al id colocarle `id="input<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>"` que será único al tenerlo en la lista del carrito

Respondiendo a la pregunta sería bueno hacer lo mismo que el input de cantidad:

-agregando class `selBodega`

-agregando `data-id="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>"`

dejando el input algo así:

`<select class="form-control form-control-sm selBodega" data-id="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Id']; ?>">`

luego para el ajax:

```
$(".selBodega").change(function(){
   var bodega = $(this).val();
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   $.ajax({
       method:'POST',
       url:'./php/actualizar_carrito.php',
       data:{
           id:id,
           bodega:bodega
       }
   });
}
```

y el manejo del backend:

```
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
if ($_SESSION['id_user'] == "") {
  echo "<script>alert('Por favor inicie sesión primero!');
  window.location.href='../'</script>";
}
$arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++){
    if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_POST['id']){
        if(isset($_POST['cantidad'])){
            $arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']=$_POST['cantidad'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['bodega'])){
            $arreglo[$i]['Bodega'] = $_POST['bodega'];
        }
        $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;
        break;
    }
    //$_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;
}
```

hice un manejo de POST para cantidad y bodega, según el que se reciba hará el cambio

Comment: ¡A la perfección!, algunos errores de sintaxis, pero todo funcionando!, Muchas gracias Kevin :D